# Why note & attachment object is not displayed in schema builder

Tags: attachment, notes, schema-builder

I am trying to create ER diagram and don't see note & attachment object. Is it just me or these object are really not available on schema builder or are they available with different names?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine they do this to prevent clutter in the UI.  You can see the erd here.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_documents.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This link tells us about relationships which i already know. I need it in schema browser.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed your assumption and commented that I suspect they do this to prevent clutter in the UI..

Comment: They have quick find there so i really doubt its to prevent clutter in the UI. If you have any authenticated info that will help.

Comment: You should NOT be using the schema builder to create an erd diagram.  FROM the docs "Schema Builder provides a dynamic environment for viewing and modifying all the objects and relationships in your app."
  Instead use a ERD creation tool that is built to support what you are doing..  The schema builder does not generate an er diagram..

Comment: Note the "viewing" that is what i am doing. i want to view it to prepare ERD.